# How to find exact matching string from sql table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I have a table which list product name . I have some product which is like ZE_QE11_IDS_IDC-P01,ZE_QE19_EIDS_UPA-Z01.

I tried

```
Select *  from products where name like 'ID'
```

The above list all the products including ZE_QE11_IDS_IDC-P01,ZE_QE19_EIDS_UPA-Z01.
I want to list only the ID from the table , how to do it

Hope you got it

Regards

Comment: It' simple to find exact match : where name = 'ID'

Comment: Select *  from products where name = 'ID'

Comment: among all these products which product will your result?

Comment: `select name` rather than `select *`?

Comment: @SandipPatel   I  put the original product name and you can see i need only the product which includes the string  IDC not EIDS . hope you got it

Comment: still not clear to me with your question updated above

Comment: `select * ... where name in ('PQ_FID03', 'PQ_IDPAT02', 'WQ_IDSMOJ23')`?

Comment: You haven't shown the definition of your table(s), without which it's hard to give a good answer.  See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: @shawnt00 , i only want to list string starting from ID .

Comment: @SandipPatel ... My  String contains a part where it starts from either IDS or EIDS . now i want to filter only  column which contain IDS

Comment: Then remove the first `%` in your `like` expression. And explain that in the question the first time around.

Comment: @shawnt00      Is there any way to filter the part which starts from IDS or EIDS

Comment: Select *  from products where name = 'ID'

Comment: How about just using `or`?

Comment: i dont think so @shawnt00

Comment: `select * from products where name like '%IDS%' and name not like '%EIDS%'` I have no idea whether this can be at the front of the string since the description is so vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case just compare with `ID` no need like clause. Like clause is required where we have to search word with some pattern OR matching word.

```
Select *  from products where name = 'ID'
```

For Updated Question:

Try below query: You have to apply logic for other character you want to eliminate as like below I have applied logic for character `E`.

```
DECLARE @myText VARCHAR(50)='ZE_QE11_IDS_IDC-P01'
SELECT @myText where @myText like '%[^E]IDS%'

Output:ZE_QE11_IDS_IDC-P01

DECLARE @myText VARCHAR(50)='ZE_QE11_EIDS_IDC-P01'
SELECT @myText where @myText like '%[^E]IDS%'

Output:
```

You can also try `SELECT @myText where @myText like '%[_]ID%'` if want to word like `_ID` only not `_EID`

Comment: After going through the comments on the question, i feel that this should be the accepted answer

Comment: how to use this in  select * from <table name>

Comment: `SELECT * from YourTableName where columnname like '%[_]ID%'`

Answer (score 0):

```
Select *  from products where name = 'ID';
```